# VPSにRubyで作ったサービスをデプロイする方法と、NetBeansを使ってRubyを開発するノウハウを知りたい

Tags: ruby, twitter, rubygems, netbeans

IDEを利用してTwitterサービスを運用しているVPSサーバーに機能をデプロイしたいです。

現在、VPSレンタルサーバーとRubyを利用してTwitterサービスを構築しています。
ソースは直接Vimを利用して書いています。しかし、IDEで定義を見に行ったり簡単にオブジェクトの依存関係を見たり、コード補完したり、ブレーク張って変数の中身を確認したりなどの、IDEの機能を使いたいのですが、ローカル環境で作成したソースをサーバーにデプロイしたり、ローカルでテストする方法がわかりません。

大雑把な質問で申し訳ないですが、IDEとRubyを利用して、Twitterサービスを構築し、ローカルでもテストする環境の構築方法を教えていただけないでしょうか。

もしくは、書籍など紹介していただけませんでしょうか。

＜使用している環境＞
・VPS
・gem twitter
・IDE netbeans
・ruby

---

take88さんからのご指摘を受けまして、以下の通り質問内容を絞って修正させていただきました。

Rubyプラグインを導入して、ローカル環境でIDEの機能を使うことは可能です。
現状のデプロイ方法は、VPSにリモートで接続し、直接vimでソースを修正してプログラムを手動または自動で実行してサービスを実現しています。

できないこと（やりたいこと）は以下になります。
1.ローカル環境のNetbeansで書いたソースをローカル環境でテスト 
2.ローカル環境のNetbeansで書いたソースをVPSにデプロイ

特に優先的に実施したいのは2.の「ローカル環境のNetbeansで書いたソースをVPSにデプロイ」です。

※ヒントなどでも構いませんので、ご教授いただけるとありがたいです。

Comment: ご自身でも書かれているように質問が大雑把、といいますか、「RubyのIDEに関する質問」と、「VPSへのデプロイの質問」と、カテゴリの違う質問が混在なので回答が付きにくい気がします。質問内容を整理して、場合によっては質問を2つに分けるなどシてみてはどうでしょう。あと、すでにNetbeansを使われているのでしたら NetbeansのRuby プラグインではダメなのでしょうか。また現状でVPSへのデプロイはどのようにされているのでしょうか。その理由や困ってる点を追記していただくとアドバイスが有るかもしれません。

Comment: 「指摘を受け修正」とありますがほとんど改善されていません。まず[ヘルプ](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help)(特に、[ヘルプセンター > 質問にあたって](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/asking))をご覧になり、take88さんの指摘をもう一度お読みになった上で質問を見直してください。「何も分からないのでやり方を一から教えて欲しい」のであれば、このサイトの利用は向きません。書籍やセミナーなどで勉強されるか、お金を出して業者に頼むことを検討された方が良いでしょう。逆にヒントを教えてくださいというのも、このサイトには向きません。

Comment: ご回答いただき。ありがとうございました。出直してまいります。